# Variety-Ideal question

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $I,J \triangleleft K\left[ {{x_1}, \ldots ,{x_n}} \right]$ such that $I \subseteq J$. Then, $V\left( J \right) \subseteq V\left( I \right)$. What about the inverse? That is, does $V\left( J \right) \subseteq V\left( I \right)$ imply $I \subseteq J$?

Comment: Can you think of two different ideals that determine the same vanishing set?

Answer (score 1):

By the [Nullstellensatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz), if $K$ is **algebraically closed**, then 
$$I(V(I)) = \sqrt{I} = \{f\in K[x_1,\dots,x_n]|\;\exists r\in \mathbb N,\;f^r\in I\}.$$
Now, $V\subseteq W \Rightarrow I(W)\subseteq I(V)$ so $V(J)\subseteq V(I) \Rightarrow \sqrt{I}\subseteq \sqrt{J}\Rightarrow I\subseteq \sqrt{J}$ and that's all (except if $J$ is radical, i.e. $\sqrt{J}=J$).

In fact, if $J=(x^2)\subseteq K[x,y]$ and $I = (x)\subseteq K[x,y]$, then $V(J)\subseteq V(I)$ but $I\not\subseteq J$.